# How to add a plugin to Eclipse Market Place

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have created an eclipse plugin "Pextools" and hosted it in http://code.google.com/p/pextools/

I also want to add it to the eclipse market place so that people who search for my plugin can find it in their marketplace-client

How to do it?

Comment: As an unrelated note: Please think about having a sub menu in your plugin. Adding _3_ entries to the project context menu is too much in my eyes, as that menu is growing with every plugin installed.

Comment: Yep! Thanks a lot! :) I too had the same opinion...
I am currently working on the shortcuts, will add them in the coming releases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Eclipse Marketplace Client displays just what is available on the [Marketplace website](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/). So register yourself there and [add an entry](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/add_content) for your plugin.